Interference in AUX connection when source is off
I have a cheap-o bluetooth speaker with an aux input that I have connected to the headphone output of my monitor. It works, but when the monitor is off there is a hum coming from the speaker that I can eliminate only by disconnecting the audio cable from the speaker or shutting off the extension cord that powers both the monitor and the speaker (speaker has battery but is USB-powered via a docking station whose power comes from the same cord).
My suspicion is a ground loop somewhere in the chain, and I am looking for suggestions on what i could measure/look for in the speaker or the monitor to confirm that and what i could hack (happy to take apart and solder stuff). I understand without proper picture/schematics it might be hard, happy to get general suggestions.
Also, monitor is not expensive but proper brand (viewsonic), while speaker is no-name amazon one, so if it's possible to fix in both places speaker is preferred as it's cheaper to replace if I mess up.

Is any of the mains powered devices having a mains plug with only 2 prongs, i.e. ungrounded plug? If yes, try another supply.

both the docking station and the monitor are 3 prong powered (monitor has an internal power supply, docking station external). there is another power supply (standing desk one) that i just added but unplugging it doesn't fix the hum, so it's probably not related.

Are they then plugged to a wall socket that actually provides ground?(I don't know what kind of plugs you have but in some parts of the world you might have old ungrounded wall sockets and they accept grounded plugs).

uk, relatively new build, i'm gonna go on a limb and say there's probably ground :)

Since it's UK, there is always 3 prongs obviously, but are the ground prongs plastic or metal? In other words, do the devices have 2-prong or 3-prong inlets; regardless of the wall plug?

all 3 prongs are metal
